# When do angels have control over their wings?

Tags: plot-explanation, lucifer

In S01E01 Amenadiel uses his wings as a weapon, they have some kind of blades at the tips. This is something that I did not see afterwards (his wings were just used as propellers, and once to physically push someone in S05).

Lucifer wings have changed along the seasons, outside of his will. Specifically, he is terrified in S04 that his wings are "bat-like". At the very end, they become white again.

Then he willingly transformed to full-fledged Lucifer, with bat-like wings and their shape was intended.

**Is there an explanation how the wings shape, color and function work in *Lucifer*?**

I have the feeling that once an angel is comfortable with himself, he has a wide control of their functionality (method of transport or weapon) and (at least Lucifer) - shape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Season 3, during the altercations with Cain, Lucifer and Amenadiel discover that Angels are self actualizing. In other words, their subconscious beliefs about themselves are what truly cause changes in their bodies. Alterations to Lucifer's wings and his control over them are likely due to changes in his perception of his own nature, as well as who he is and who he sees himself as. A great example is the return of his devil face after he kills Cain. He doesn't necessarily feel guilty about killing Cain, but rather for disobeying his father. Thus he has once again rebelled, and is once again the Devil.

Comment: The extension of that is that Amenadiel's "combat" wings are an extension of his belief on who he is, i.e. an enforcer. Which is exactly how he thinks of himself at the start.

Comment: Very true. Their wings are also bestowed by God as part of their being, and seeing as how angels are incredibly powerful, it's not like one would expect their wings to be hollow-boned pieces of fluff. They're powerful muscle-bound appendages, capable of propelling them between Heaven, Hell, and Earth.